# Loop Through Each Character in Golang

Tags: loops, go

I have a variable string in Go. How can I check if current character equals to next character?

My code like this, but still error:

```
   message := "hhappy"

    for i, v := range message {
      if v[i] == v[i+1] {
        //print something
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

Since `rune` can be larger than a single byte [(1 to 4 bytes)](https://blog.golang.org/strings), you can't really check the next item in the slice, since some chars (other than ASCII) can be larger than a single byte. This will fail your code.

One correct option is to iterate the string elements, comparing each char to the previous one. This way if a `rune` repeats itself, the code will still work. For example,

```
func main() {
    var prev rune
    message := "hhappyèèaa"
    for i, v := range message {
        if prev == 0 {
            prev = v
            continue
        }
        if prev == v {
            fmt.Printf("previous char: %s curr pos: %v\n", string(v), i)
        }
        prev = v
    }
}
```

outputs

```
previous char: h curr pos: 1
previous char: p curr pos: 4
previous char: è curr pos: 8
previous char: a curr pos: 11
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use v[i] as v is a rune when you range over message string.

Below code can be used:

```
  message := "tesssting"
  for i := 0; i < len(message)-2; i++ {
      if message[i] == message[i+1] {
         // print something
      }
  }
```

Comment: this does not take multibite characters into account